# Arrow key navigation to input text inside div

Tags: javascript

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ4PJ/) shows my technique for arrow key navigation. How can I do the same using the following HTML, skipping the `<br>` tag?

```
<div class='move'>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think @GeneR don't know how to see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35667549/revisions#) of a post. If he knows about it then he wont confuses himself by seeing me formatting the OP's code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='move'><input /></div>
<div class='move'><input /></div>
<div class='move'><input /></div>

$(document).keydown(
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      $(".move>input:focus").parent().next().children().focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      $(".move>input:focus").parent().prev().children().focus();
    }
  }
);
```

But i'd made this way:

```
$('.move>input').keydown(
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      $(this).parent().next().children().focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      $(this).parent().prev().children().focus();
    }
  }
);
```